# When to use snap-off blade knife and when to use trapezoid blade knife?

Tags: cutting

I want to buy a utility knife, but I don't know what are the advantages of snap-off blade knife over trapezoid blade and vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

Trapezoid razor blades are stronger, so they can be used for cutting thick or very tough materials better than snapping blades. Examples where I use this blade:

1. Cutting carpet or vinyl
2. Cutting/carving wood where cleanness of the cut isn’t important

Snapping blades are super convenient when making lots of cuts on materials that dull or gum up blades quick and the material isn’t really thick or tough.

1. Cutting packing tape
2. Cutting thin/medium gauge cardboard

Comment: Agree, and will add that having a long (Olfa brand is my usual) blade is good for insulation and shaving almost-set-bondo. Note that having the blade out all the way is a great way to have the blade snap and hit you in the face.